# Count the Number of string patterns using regular expressions from a File

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I created the file 'file1.txt' having "hello" as a searched pattern. Below program count the number of lines perfectly, although the issue here is with the word or pattern count "hello". For the same line, if there are 3 'hello', still it only count only one. In my file there are total 13 'hello' pattern. Among them 2 lines have 3 'hello' pattern. So, Ultimately the answer I am getting is 9 instead of 13. So, for each of the line it count as only 1. How to solve this issue ?

```
import re

def reg_exp():
    pattern = 'hello'
    infile = open('file1.txt', 'r')
    match_count = 0
    lines = 0

    for line in infile:
        match = re.search(pattern, line)
        if match:
            match_count += 1
            lines += 1
    return (lines, match_count)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lines, match_count = reg_exp()
    print 'LINES::', lines
    print 'MATCHES::', match_count
```

Answer (score 2):

That's how regex works. [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) returns as soon as it finds the first match. You could iterate with [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer), or use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to return all matches for each line.

```
for line in infile:
    match = re.findall(pattern, line)   
    if match:
        match_count += len(match)
        lines += 1
```

<kbd>[ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/7eVJF9)</kbd>

---

> [re.**search**(pattern, string, flags=0)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search)
>
> Scan through string looking for
> **the first location** where the regular expression pattern produces a
> match, and return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if
> no position in the string matches the pattern; note that this is
> different from finding a zero-length match at some point in the
> string.

---

> [re.**findall**(pattern, string, flags=0)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)
>
> Return **all non-overlapping matches**
> of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is
> scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If
> one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of
> groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one
> group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the
> beginning of another match.

Answer (score -1):

```
def reg_exp():
    pattern = '(hello)'
    infile = open('file1.txt', 'r')
    match_count = 0
    lines = 0

    for line in infile:
        match = re.search(pattern, line)
        if match:
            match_count += len(match.groups())
            lines += 1
    return (lines, match_count)
```

Comment: Tried. But the "match count" becomes 0.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I think setting pattern = '(hello)' will work in conjunction with the groups().

Comment: Could you just write that expression ?

Comment: My python skills must be too rusty from years of non-use! Coulda sworn that would have worked :(.

Comment: Mariano is correct. Findall is necessary to find all matches instead of search. It is the closest thing in python to the global search flag (/g).